# Optimizing the number of constructor calls

Tags: c++, constructor, g++

At work we have a class with an expensive constructor so we would like it to be called as few times as possible. We looked through the uses of it and tried to make the code more RVO friendly so to say.

However we found a quirk in the g++ compiler where we didn't understand what happened.

Please consider the two implementations of operator+

```
const Imaginary Imaginary::operator+(const Imaginary& rhs) const
{
    Imaginary tmp(*this);
    tmp.append(rhs);
    return tmp;
}
```

and

```
const Imaginary Imaginary::operator+(const Imaginary& rhs) const
{
    return Imaginary(*this).append(rhs);
}
```

I have put print-outs in the the various constructors and with the following little program

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Imaginary x(1, 1);
    Imaginary y(2, 1);

    Imaginary c = x + y;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this print out with the first implementation of operator+

```
int/int ctor
int/int ctor
Copy ctor
```

And I get the following when the second variant of operator+ is in use

```
int/int ctor
int/int ctor
Copy ctor
Copy ctor
```

Here we see that g++ is able to optimize away one call to the copy constructor in one case but not the latter and to my surprise, it managed to do it with the *more clumsy* implementation where I saved it to a temporary.

Now I could've understood it more if it was the other way around but appearantly it isn't
and now I am hoping that maybe one you could enlighten me on this subject.

I should probably add that when we add --no-elide-constructors as a flag to g++
I get the following print out

```
int/int ctor
int/int ctor
Copy ctor
Copy ctor
Copy ctor
```

Regards, Mattias

Comment: Welcome to SO, and good job writing the question.

Comment: Guideline: Don’t copy your function arguments. Instead, pass them by value and let the compiler do the copying. (http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/). Maybe not relevant here, but might be interesting four you.

Comment: In C++11 define a move constructor for your class, then even without NRVO, the returning will not be expensive (assuming move is cheap).

Comment: I was so amazed by this I had to ask it on the [gcc-help list](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2013-12/msg00132.html).

Comment: Don't return a const object, it prevents the return value being eligible for move semantics

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Better say "It prevents the return value from matching the *usual* move constructor signature."  `X(const X&&)` is also a move constructor according to the Standard, although extremely rare.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I didn't say it can't match a move ctor, I said it's not eligible for move semantics. A constructor taking a const rvalue reference may be a "move constructor" but doesn't implement move semantics.

Answer (score 5):

If the compiler cannot inline `append`, then it cannot determine that the return value is target object.  Then it doesn't know that the temporary is being returned, and cannot construct it in place.

You would have the same behavior with:

```
Imaginary tmp(*this);
return tmp.append(rhs);
```

If the return value of `append` is opaque to the compiler (defined in another compilation unit), it prevents the optimization.

Comment: Well Ben, can that really be the answer, I mean both implementations of append are equally visible in this case. The entire implementation of the class Imaginary is in the same file as main() and I can't really see the difference between having a named temporary to return or an anonymous as in the second implementation.

Comment: @Mattias: If it's too big to inline, the compiler will most likely still not perform the optimization.  You might try with `inline Imaginary& Imaginary::append( const Imaginary& rhs ) { append_impl(rhs); return *this; }` and see whether that makes the optimization possible again.

Comment: I tried with inline for the append method but it didn't change anything, it's still 3 constructor calls with the named temporary implementation and 4 calls for the anonymous variant.

Comment: @Mattias: Did you break out the return part from the implementation like I suggested, in order to make sure it's small enough to inline?

Comment: Inlining cannot affect copy elision.

Comment: @ArtemGr: NRVO, where the compiler places the named variable in the storage which the calling convention designates for return, is independent of inlining.  But RVO, where the function constructs its return value directly into the caller's storage, has the same conditions as inlining: The compiler must see the function's body at the call site, and develop a custom calling convention (perhaps a reference to the return value storage location is passed, instead of placing it in a register or onto the stack).

Comment: RVO does not work between independent compilation units -- the caller and callee must agree on the location where the result will be placed.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Please notice that I said "the compiler **cannot** inline", not that it chooses not to, for example because of size of the target function.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That depends on the default calling conventions available to the compiler, doesn't it? I've tried the Wikipedia RVO example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) with GCC 4.8.2: https://gist.github.com/ArtemGr/8043091 - and it looks to me like the RVO is performed across the compilation unit boundaries, I see "Hello World!" with no copies.

Comment: That example looks like it has most vexing parse issues.

Answer (score 0):

Stephan T. Lavavej mentions in
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler
that (N)RVO only happens when the type of the returned value is exactly the same as the type returned from the method.

For example:

```
string foo() {string tmp; return tmp;}  // Same type, uses NRVO or automatic move.
string foo() {const string& tmp = "bar"; return tmp;}  // Types differ, no NRVO, nor automatic move.
string foo() {string tmp; string& ref = tmp; return ref;}  // Types differ, no NRVO, nor automatic move.
string foo() {string tmp; return (string&) tmp;}  // Types differ, no NRVO, nor automatic move.
```

(cf. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79e79e5bb0350584)

I guess `append` returns a *reference* to Imaginary, and as `Imaginary&` is not of the same type as `Imaginary` this prevents (N)RVO.

Comment: In my MWE, with the first operator+ and `void append(Imaginary const & rhs)` I get one copy, with `Imaginary append(...` I get two copies and with `Imaginary & append(...` again just one copy. With the second operator+, both `Imaginary append(...` and `Imaginary & append(...` gives two copies.

Comment: @Mankka: That made no sense to me. If you imply that append should return `Imaginary` then I never said that nor would I agree with that.