# GCC NRVO/RVO warning

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, copy-elision

Is there any *warning*, which allows us to know whether **NRVO/RVO** performed or not, in **GCC**?

I found that `-fno-elide-constructors` turns off **NRVO/RVO**, but **NRVO/RVO** has its own conditions to occur and sometimes does not occur. There is a need to know if **NRVO/RVO** occurs to understand, when extra copy-construction happens.

I am especially interested in compile-time features. It would be nice if there were some specific `#pragma GCC...` (which activates the diagnostic immediately following itself) or something using static assertion mechanism.

Comment: to my knowledge, compilers do not tend to inform you about this kind of optimizations, especially if they happen or not and when and why, but there are some guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320520/optimizing-the-number-of-constructor-calls

Comment: It is strange in light of presence of warnings like`-Winline`.

Comment: `-Wdisabled-optimization` not giving anything? Then you can still look if the output of `-fdump-ipa-all` tells you something.

Comment: @Damon how to check `-Wdisabled-optimization` is workable? I can't obtain any `.nrv` output files with `-fdump-tree-nrv`, and it seems, that `-fopt-info-nrv-missed`/`-fopt-info-missed-nrv` does not exists.

Comment: Works for me, it puts the `.nrv` file next to the `.o` file -- the bigger challenge is reading through that mess, since they're not precisely very human-friendly files. I've only used `-Wdisabled-optimization` myself once or twice, since the "noise" was too annoying with very little benefit in return. It seemed to work fine (for what it does) back then, though.

Comment: `tree-nrv` is for a basic, late, language-agnostic optimization, not the strong C++ N?RVO, which happens much earlier in the front-end. Filing an RFE in gcc's bugzilla would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any warning, which allows us to know whether NRVO/RVO
> performed or not, in GCC?

`gcc (trunk)` (not yet released v14) has [`-Wnrvo`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wnrvo)

*"Warn if the compiler does not elide the copy from a local variable to the return value of a function in a context where it is allowed by [class.copy.elision]. This elision is commonly known as the Named Return Value Optimization."*

`gcc (trunk)` is available on https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of any gcc specific diagnostic message or other method that easily can solve your task. As you have found out, `-fno-elide-constructors` will disable copy/move elisions, so you will know for sure that (N)RVO will not happen in that case at least.

However, a quick look at paragraph 31 in section 12.8 of [this C++11 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) states that:

> When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the copy/move
>   constructor and/or destructor for the object have side effects. In
>   such cases, **the implementation treats the source and target of the
>   omitted copy/move operation as simply two different ways of referring
>   to the same object**, and the destruction of that object occurs at the
>   later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed
>   without the optimization. This elision of copy/move operations,
>   called copy elision, is permitted in the following circumstances
>   (**which may be combined to eliminate multiple copies**):
>
> - **in a return statement in a function with a class return type, when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object** (other
>     than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified
>     type as the function return type, the copy/move operation can be
>     omitted by constructing the automatic object directly into the
>     function’s return value
>
> ...
>
> - **when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference** (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same
>     cv-unqualified type, the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>     constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
>     omitted copy/move
>
> ...

When copy/move elision happen the local auto object is the same as the temporary (return) object, which in turn is the same as the "storage" object (where the return value is stored). So the local auto object is the same as the storage object, which means a pointer comparison will equal true. A simple example to demonstrate this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> testNRVO(int value, size_t size, const std::vector<int> **localVec)
{
   std::vector<int> vec(size, value);

   *localVec = &vec;

   /* Do something here.. */

   return vec;
}

int main()
{
   const std::vector<int> *localVec = nullptr;

   std::vector<int> vec = testNRVO(0, 10, &localVec);

   if (&vec == localVec)
      std::cout << "NRVO was applied" << std::endl;
   else
      std::cout << "NRVO was not applied" << std::endl;
}
```

Enabling/disabling `-fno-elide-constructors` changes the printed message as expected. Note: in the strictest sense the pointer comparison might be depending on undefined behavior when (N)RVO does not happen, since the local auto object is non-existing.

Doing pointer comparisons will add cruft, but with the advantage of compiler-independency.

Comment: Won't taking address of local can sometimes prevent optimizations?